# Can't do an insert with select on a locked table

Tags: mysql, locking

I need to add rows into a locked table (for some reasons) without inserting duplicates.
I wrote this script, trying to use an INSERT..SELECT.

```
START TRANSACTION;
LOCK TABLES table WRITE;

INSERT INTO table  (id, fullName) 
SELECT '12', "mathis plapp" FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE fullName='mathis plapp' LIMIT 1);
          
UNLOCK TABLES;
COMMIT;
```

Without lock, the script works perfectly well. But with the lock, I get

> Table 'table' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

I tried many other ways, (temp tables ...) but can't manage to make that work.

PS : i have no constraints on columns.

PPS : I can't alter the table in any way

PPPS :

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-------------------------+
| VERSION()               |
+-------------------------+
| 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use a unique index to prevent duplicate values from being inserted rather than this overcomplicated solution you came up with?

Comment: because I can't (client's DB which is crappy)

Comment: then add the unique index to the table

Comment: I can't (otherwise I wouldn't ask anything)

Comment: This is an important detail that you should add to the question! We cannot possibly know that you are aware of unique indexes and that you cannot use it. Although, I do suggest to have a conversation with your client around this as your current code can have significant performance constraint on the application!

Comment: agreed. I will but what if they don't want to alter the table (very likely) ?

Comment: You need to explain that either they can use a standard functionality that the database server offers out-of-the-box, or they can spend time and money to replicate the same functionality with application code that needs time to implement, test and then maintain and may result in a lower performance.

Answer (score 0):

After like two days of investigation, I found that a stored procedure can do the job.

First execute this to create and store the procedure in the table :

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE insertGuy(IN newId int, IN newName VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE nameExists INT;
    
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO nameExists FROM `table` WHERE name = newName;
    
    IF nameExists = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO `table` (id, fullName) VALUES (newId, newName);
    END IF;
    
END

DELIMITER ;
```

Then it's possible to do this insertion within a locked region.

```
START TRANSACTION;

LOCK TABLES `table` WRITE;

CALL insertGuy(20, 'diane');
CALL insertGuy(21, 'regis');

UNLOCK TABLES;

COMMIT;
```